# Is it possible to use Bash history expansion inside the trap command?

Tags: bash, bash-trap

Is it possible to use history expansion within a `trap [commands] ERR`?
I've tried manually enabling history expansion within the environment and within the trap commands argument (`trap 'set -H; echo !-2 failed' ERR`) but could not get it to work as the shell always ended up just interpreting "!-2" literally.

Every designator I've tried from [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators) ended up being interpreted literally once the trap got activated but they work just fine when called somewhere else in the same environment.

Comment: Are you running this in a script?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I am.

Comment: There is "history" in noninteractive scripts (well, unless you enable it). How doesn't `BASH_COMMAND` or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/trap-err-and-echoing-the-error-line doesn't do what you want? Isn't this XY question. You are _not_ interested in expanding `!-2` in `trap` context... What you are interested, is how to get failed command in ERR trap..

Answer (score 0):

`!-2`? Use:

```
history | tail -n2 | head -n1
```

or just:

```
history -p '!-2'
```